# Ngnix rewrite with catchall server_name

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Im trying to do a rewrite based on a catchall server name.

So I would like any domain that hits this server for example

> demo.example.com

to be rewrote to

> example.org?site=demo.example.com

Currently I have the catchall server setup as

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name ~^(.+)$;


    location / {
            rewrite ^ http://example.org?site=$host permanent;
    }
}
```

However, 
the above config is taking me to

> http://example.org/?site=~^(.+)$

I have tried using $server_name in the rewrite with no luck either.
Any ideas?

Comment: What request gives you that redirect?

Comment: you aren't capturing the server name (`~^(?<ibecomeavariable>.+)`) - but as dookie points out below, you don't need to either.

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck with this.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://example.org/$1?site=$host permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: no location block and just `return 301 http://example.com$request_uri?site=$host;` would be "better".